# Use of frequency argument in window function

Tags: r, forecasting

Suppose that I have the following loop which computes rolling forecasts with model re-fitting using ARMA models.

```
    library(forecast)
    set.seed(1)
    prices=rnorm(1963)
    USDlogreturns=diff(log(prices))
    h <- 1
    train <- window(USDlogreturns, end=1162, frequency=1)
    test <- window(USDlogreturns, start=1163, frequency=1)
    n <- length(test) - h + 1
    fc1 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1163+1, freq=1)
    fc2 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1163+1, freq=1)
    fc3 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1163+1, freq=1)
    fc4 <- ts(numeric(n), start=1163+1, freq=1)
    fit1 <- Arima(train, order=c(0,0,0), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
    fit2 <- Arima(train, order=c(0,0,1), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
    fit3 <- Arima(train, order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
    fit4 <- Arima(train, order=c(1,0,1), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
    for(i in 1:n){  
      x <- window(USDlogreturns, end=1162 + i, frequency=100)
      refit1 <- Arima(x, model=fit1, include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      refit2 <- Arima(x, model=fit2, include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      refit3 <- Arima(x, model=fit3, include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      refit4 <- Arima(x, model=fit4, include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      fc1[i] <- forecast(refit1, h=h)$mean[h]
      fc2[i] <- forecast(refit2, h=h)$mean[h]
      fc3[i] <- forecast(refit3, h=h)$mean[h]
      fc4[i] <- forecast(refit4, h=h)$mean[h]
    }
```

As I run it in R, I get 50 warning messages which run:

"In window.default(USDlogreturns, end = 1162 + i, frequency = 100) :'frequency' not changed"

So my problem is that I am struggling to understand how to tell R to refit my four ARMA models every 100 days for 8 times through the window function.

Any tips for a rookie?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `frequency` in those calls to `window`? It looks like you're trying to control the width of the window, but `frequency` isn't used for that. It's used to specify the periodicity of the time series, and `frequency = 1` indicates annual data.

Comment: Yes my problem is that want to generate 1-day-ahead forecasts with model refitting occurring every 100 days but do not know how to tell this through the command window.

Comment: I think you'll want to write a function inside a call to `lapply` or `sapply`, with a vector of sample break points (e.g., `seq(0, 800, 100)`) as the `X` in that call. Try writing code for the first and second iterations of that process, then turn the bit(s) you change for the 2nd into the variable(s) in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem myself. The use of the "pos" command provides a much more flexible and elegant solution by the way.

```
length_training <- 1162
    start <- length_training + 1
    end <- length(USDlogreturns) 
    forecast_length <- 1
    for(pos in start:end) {
      fit000 <- Arima(USDlogreturns[(pos-length_training):(pos-1)], order=c(0,0,0), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      fc000 <- forecast(fit000, h=forecast_length)$mean[forecast_length]
      fit001 <- Arima(USDlogreturns[(pos-length_training):(pos-1)], order=c(0,0,1), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      fc001 <- forecast(fit001, h=forecast_length)$mean[forecast_length]
      fit100 <- Arima(USDlogreturns[(pos-length_training):(pos-1)], order=c(1,0,0), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      fc100 <- forecast(fit100, h=forecast_length)$mean[forecast_length]
      fit101 <- Arima(USDlogreturns[(pos-length_training):(pos-1)], order=c(1,0,1), include.mean=TRUE, method="ML")
      fc101 <- forecast(fit101, h=forecast_length)$mean[forecast_length]
    }
```